# How do I add cases to a switch statement using javascript by getting json data from a database using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Right now I have an application where a user clicks a generate button and a random object is created using the function below. There is also a checklist. The user checks off a bunch of options and only the checked options can be randomly chosen and turned into an object.

What I want to do is take the checklist to another page and use php to store which checkboxes have been checked. Then on another page have the application which uses this function to get that data(checked boxes data) from the database (using mysql).

The best way I could think to acheive this is:
When they have checked the boxes and saved the results, have php write json text. Then before the application starts, retrieve the json in javascript using ajax.

So fundamentally,  what i want is to create case statements using the data from the database, and have this function complete to use for the application.

(There are many case statements and more objects, such as 'object c' will be dynamically added through a CMS so I cant just put all the details in the js file. thats why I need everything in a database)

If anyone has any better ideas to achieve this, im very happy to listen :')

```
function getObj(objName) {
switch(objName) {
        case 'a':
            var x = new Object('name1','id1');
            x.entrance = ['1','3','4'];
            x.exit = ['2','3'];
            return x;

        case 'b':
            var x = new Object('name2','id2');
            x.entrance = ['2','3','6'];
            x.exit = ['2','3','7'];
            return x;

        default:
            console.log('Error at object conversion. Object was not found');
            break;
}
```

}

Comment: Why not dynamically generate the JavaScript switch statement based on the selected values in PHP?

Comment: yeh I thought about doing that too. but i couldn't find how to get that code into a javascript file. thats why i gave up on that idea ^^; I can't have it in the php/html file using the script tag coz the rest of the app wouldn't work. could you shed some light on how to put  json text into javascript as working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass json data like this from php:

```
{
    'a': {
        'id': 'id1',
        'name': 'name1',
        'entrance': [1, 2, 4],
        'exit': [2, 3]
    },

    'b': {
        'id': 'id2',
        'name': 'name2',
        'entrance': [2, 3, 6],
        'exit': [2, 3, 7]
    }
}
```

than in javascript after having the json string parsed to an object simply access the corresponding property:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);

function getObj(objName) {
    return data[objName];
}
```

content enclosed in `{}` represents an object, and will be decoded to one by `JSON.parse()`. if you are using jQuerys `ajax()` method, the data will have already been parsed automatically.

Comment: Not gonna lie, I think I love you..

so if the string 'a' ended up as the argument for 'objName', the object 'a': {
        'id': 'id1',
        'name': 'name1',
        'entrance': [1, 2, 4],
        'exit': [2, 3]
    } 
will be created right? :'D

Comment: no. you would get the same as: `var x = new Object(); x.id = 'id1'; x.name = 'name1', x.entrance = ['1','3','4']; x.exit = ['2','3'];` i assumed you did not want to have: `x.name1 = 'id1'`. this is what your `var x = new Object('name1','id1')` is creating.

Comment: Ah yes my mistake. i meant 'x' :)
even though i edited the comment like 500 times and refered to it as 'a' each time. Thanks so much man, was racking my brain over this.

Comment: it's not about x or a. the properties are different. but of course you can change them to your liking.